# Adjective-No in a Question format?

Tags: particle-の, questions, i-adjectives, sentence

I'm having a difficult time understanding the use of の-Adj in the JLPT N5 grammar examples and practice I've been studying and haven't found a good resource for finding the answer. The sentence is fairly simple but I can't tell what the purpose of the の at the end of the Adj is in it. It goes:

> 大きいのは　いくらですか。 Ookii-no wa ikura desuka?

Does anybody have any clue? Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39042/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58551/9831

Answer (score 5):

の in this case is a pronoun that can be translated to English as "one".

(More precisely, it's a "dependent indefinite pronoun")

Therefore:

> 大きい = "big" (adjective)
>
> 大きいの = "big one" (noun equivalent)

By applying this translation, we can see the problem that happens if we don't use の:

> *大きいはいくらですか = "how much is the big" (wrong)
>
> 大きいのはいくらですか = "how much is the big one" (correct)

For more research on uses of の, I recommend reading the relevant chapters of the book "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a nominalizer. When you nominalize an adjective, the meaning becomes "the fact that it is Adj." e.g., 大きいのこと. Further evidence: ボブ is a noun; ボブの meaning "Bob's" is not a nominalized version of ボブ. I'm not sure what part of speech the の here is, however; I want to call it a pronoun, but it's not replacing a noun per se. The example sentences are correct, of course!

Comment: hmm yep I think you're right. I spoke too soon. I'll fix up my sloppy terminology. (fixed now)

Comment: @mamster You can have different kinds of nominalisers with different meanings - all a nominaliser is is a thing that turns something into a noun of some kind. I'd have no problem describing の here as a nominaliser; and really, it sounds much more to me like that than like a pronoun.

Comment: whatever the most accurate description may be, the current description is based on the wording used in the cited reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 318:

> の: a nominalizer which is used when the nominalized sentence expresses a directly perceptible event. (...)
>
> Example sentence(s):
>   日本へ行くのは簡単です。
>   Going to Japan is easy.
>
> ...
>
> Formation:
>   話すのは
>   The act of talking
>
> 高いのは
>   The expensive one
>
> 静かだったのは
>   The one that was quiet
>
> ...
>
> の makes a noun equivalent from a sentence.
>
> ...
>
> There is another nominalizer こと. の and こと are sometimes mutually interchangeable. For example, [日本へ行くのは簡単です。] can be restated as:
>
> 日本へ行くことは簡単です。
>   Going to Japan is easy.

Comment: see the comment discussion on my answer

Comment: This is very helpful. 勉強になりました。